# collapse rows in 2 different columns in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

For dummy dataset

```
require(data.table)
require(reshape2)
teamid <- c(1,2,3)
member <- c("a,b","","c,g,h")
leader <- c("c", "d,e", "")
dt <- data.table(teamid, member, leader)
```

Now the dataset looks like this:

```
   teamid member leader
1:      1    a,b      c
2:      2           d,e
3:      3  c,g,h
```

3 Columns. For each team, they have team members, and team leaders in different column. Teams may have only members without leaders, and vice versa.

The following is my **ALMOST** desired output:

```
   teamid value leader
1:      1     a  FALSE
2:      1     b  FALSE
3:      1     c   TRUE
4:      1     c   TRUE
5:      2     d   TRUE
6:      2     e   TRUE
7:      3     c  FALSE
8:      3     g  FALSE
9:      3     h  FALSE
```

I want to have the two columns merged into one, and add a tag if one is a team leader.

I have an ugly solution for this,

`dt1 <- dt[, strsplit(member, ","), by = teamid]
dt2 <- dt[, strsplit(leader, ","), by = teamid]
setkey(dt1,teamid)
setkey(dt2,teamid)
dt3 <- merge(dt1,dt2, all = TRUE)
dt4 <- melt(dt3, id = 1, measure = c("V1.x", "V1.y"))
dt5 <- dt4[value!="NA_real"]
dt6 <- dt5[, leader := (variable == "V1.y")][, variable := NULL]
setkey(dt6, teamid)
setnames(dt6,value,member)`

Issues:

1. This solution is not efficency I think, first merge and then melt. So any ideas about other ways to do this?
2. There're duplicated rows, in row 3 and row 4.
3. When I tried to change column name, an error came up

> setnames(dt6,value,member)
>
> Error in setnames(dt6, value, member) : object 'value' not found

Maybe the most important thing,

When I tried to test on my real dataset, which have more 1million rows, 3 columns the following error occured

> merge(df1,df2, all = TRUE)
>   Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian) NULL else as.integer(max(nrow(x),  : 
>     Join results in 238797 rows; more than 142095 = max(nrow(x),nrow(i)). Check for duplicate key values in i, each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try including `j` and dropping `by` (by-without-by) so that j runs for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.

Any suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Melt first.

```
result <- melt(dt,id="teamid", variable.name="status", value.name="member")
result <- result[nchar(member)>0,strsplit(member,","),by=list(teamid,status)]
setnames(result,"V1","member")
setkey(result,teamid,status)
result
#    teamid status member
# 1:      1 member      a
# 2:      1 member      b
# 3:      1 leader      c
# 4:      2 leader      d
# 5:      2 leader      e
# 6:      3 member      c
# 7:      3 member      g
# 8:      3 member      h
```

If you want to get rid of the `status` column and add a "tag" to the member column, you can do it this way:

```
result[status=="leader",member:=paste0(member,"*")]
result[,status:=NULL]
result
#    teamid member
# 1:      1      a
# 2:      1      b
# 3:      1     c*
# 4:      2     d*
# 5:      2     e*
# 6:      3      c
# 7:      3      g
# 8:      3      h
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler approach may be

```
crew <- dt[, .(strsplit(member, ","))]
crew <- unlist(crew)
leads <- dt[, .(strsplit(leader, ","))]
leads <- unlist(leads)

dt_long <- data.table(people=c(crew, leads), 
    status = rep(c("crew", "leader"), c(length(crew), length(leader))))
```

It gives me

```
  people status
1:      a   crew
2:      b   crew
3:      c   crew
4:      g   crew
5:      h   crew
6:      c leader
7:      d leader
8:      e leader
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a tidyverse solution now

```
dt %>% 
  separate_rows(member) %>% 
  separate_rows(leader) %>% 
  gather(status, member, -teamid) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  filter(member != "") %>% 
  mutate(member=ifelse(status == "leader", paste0(member, "*"), member)) %>% 
  select(-status)
  teamid member
1      1      a
2      1      b
3      3      c
4      3      g
5      3      h
6      1     c*
7      2     d*
8      2     e*
```